# jQuery custom widgets: how can I include a html template?

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-plugins, jquery-widgets

I must be missing something basic here but while developing a custom jQuery widget, how do we include a html template as part of the widget like we do with dojo custom widgets? Currently, my jQuery custom widget is generating the needed html in JavaScript and I am trying to take that out into a html template and include it with the custom widget. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/). THis is a jQuery template plugin and The syntax is pretty easy

Declare a Templae with `script` tag

```
  <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div class="body">
           {{body}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Then fetch and compile that template like this

```
  var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

Then you can render that template by passing data for `palceholders` like this

```
 var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"}
 var html    = template(context);
```

After this you will have the ful `html` in `html` variable which you can use in any jQuery DOM manipulation method like `$.append`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/4BLgj/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I ended up using the underscore templating system that ships with backbone since I am using backbone.js anyway and load the html snippet in the _create method of the widget and use the template methods to load the data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a plugin or anything fancy to do what you're trying to do. Widgets can be created easily enough by simply creating html files with the appropriate markup and any jQuery calls you need. For example you can create a main page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- reference jquery library here -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#wdg1").load("mywidget.html");
        $("#wdg2").load("mywidget.html");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wdg1"></div>
<div id="wdg2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then your `mywidget.html` file will look something like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Widget loaded.");
        // run whatever code you want here.
    });
</script>
<span>This span was loaded as a widget.</span>
```